# Dataframe subsetting on a variable with the same value

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, co

I have a simple data frame like this:

```
col1    col2
a       1   
b       2
a       2
```

I'll refer to this data frame as `table`. I am trying to create variables `a1` and `a2` where the value of `a1` would be 1 in this instance and the value of `a2` would be 2. My current attempt is this to get `a1` and `a2`:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(table)) {
  
  # Getting a1
  if (col1 == 'a') {
    a1 <- as.numeric(table %>% dplyr::select(col2))
  } else {
    if (a1 != 0) {
      a1 <- a1
    } else {
      a1 <- 0
    }
  }

 # Getting a2
 if (col1 == 'a' & a1 != 0) {
    a2 <- as.numeric(table %>% dplyr::select(col2))
  } else {
    if (a2 != 0) {
      a2 <- a2
    } else {
      a2 <- 0
    }
  }

}
```

With this I get `a1` and `a2` to be 2. So the loops are correctly identifying the 2nd instance where `col1 = 'a'` but for `a1` I need the first instance where `col1 = 'a'` which keeps getting overwritten.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: Can you explain precisely how values in the new dataframe columns a1 and a2 are a function of the existing columns col1 and col2?

Comment: The desired output is to have a1 be just 1 and a2 to be 2

Comment: Col2 is a specific ID for each value of of col1. So if col1 contained a, b, and c, I could have 4 values of a, 3 values of b, and 5 values of c. It’s a within variable identifier kind of